# Convert Location to GeoPoint

Tags: android, google-maps, location, overlay

All- I am trying to get the user's current location than display that on the map with an overlay item. My problem is the user's location is coming in as a location and the overlay array only accepts GeoPoints. Here is what I have tried:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {      
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint.valueOf(location);
            OverlayItem overlayitem4 = new OverlayItem(point, "You Are Here", "Boulder, CO");               
        }
```

But I am getting an error on `GeoPoint.valueOf(location);`, specifically:

> GeoPoint.valueOf cannot be resolved to a type`

So my question is **How can I convert from location to GeoPoint?** Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {      
         int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
         int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
         GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
         OverlayItem overlayitem4 = new OverlayItem(point, "You Are Here",   "Boulder, CO"); 
     }
}
```

Comment: This solves my immediate problem thank you you will get the "check mark" but now I can't add it via 'itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem4);' because the array is declared out side of its scope. Any idea on how to get overlayitem4 outside of the onLocationsChanged method?

Comment: of course you can declarate overlayitem4 everywhere. if you need to use it as a global variable you have to declarate at the very begging of your class

Comment: I tried to do this: public class MainActivity extends MapActivity { 
 OverlayItem currentP; and that got rid of the errors but when I ran it I got NullPointerException. What should I initialize it to to start off?

Comment: no you don't need to initialize unless you use it before assigning value. could you post your code on pastebin.com and I could hava a look

Comment: ok. I think I got it. if you don't undestand something sorry for may english in advance, I try to expalain again. the issue is you do that  itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(currentP); on the onCreate methode but probably the onLocationChanged methode doesn't trigger becouse doesn't get any update location yet it takes time. so what you should do is that add this line itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(currentP); inside onLocationChanged (at the end).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me and it seems much easier:

```
GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(location);
```

Comment: This no longer works as tested in firebase version 12.0.1.